# How to load image from a redirected url in android

Tags: android, image, url, redirect, imageview

I am trying to load image in ImageView. The URL for image,when I hit it on web browser, it redirects me to another link for the image.

When I use the same URL for ImagView I get the error for File Not Found Exception: URL

Is there any way I can get the image loaded from redirected url.

**UPDATE**

This is the URL I hit

http://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/picture/

and in response for example I get image from below URL

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif

Comment: can U share the redirected image url. did U tried in normal PC browser?

Comment: may be this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470227/how-is-it-possible-to-know-that-the-link-will-be-redirected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know it's too late, you've probably figured it out. in android ImageView can not handle remote URL, so the problem is not url redirect.